# get data from Db Column and make it Proper URl?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, vb.net

i have  one  single column contain Multiple URL`s by "," separate  i want to get these URL proper and Show in J query Slider in my asp.net page.

Column Detail like
"ID", "URLS"
 1   ,www.abc.com/abc.jpg, wwww.bcd.com/ced.jpeg, 
lots  of Image URL`s in one Single Column value.

Need your Suggetions

Comment: get the column value and split using ',' and access that

Comment: string[] url=urldatabasecolumn.Split(',');

Comment: Thank you Guys i have Done by Spliting first my Array and then made Proper URl .. thank you ...  for your Kind Feed back .

Comment: What about URLs that contain commas? It's allowed and would break what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sPhotoURL = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["PHOTO_LOCATIONColumnName"]);
string[] words = sPhotoURL.Split(',');
int count = 0;
hdnImageCount.Value = words.Length.ToString();
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word.Length > 50)
    {
        count += 1;
        String correctURl = word.Substring(45);
        string photoNumber = correctURl.Substring(1, 2);
        correctURl = "http://" + "images-+photoNumber+urlsomething/something/"+correctURl;
        string url = correctURl;
    }
}
```

This will made my correct URl and after that I pass this to function to download images.

Thank you all I done this by the following code ...